# Image not opening in Lightbox in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 1.5 and i have tried a lot but could not able to load the images in lightbox extension.

Please guide me what i am missing there as all the components and modules not showing the images in Lightbox, really frustrating. 
Using below url in index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/foldrname/engine1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Guide me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug using `Firebug`, look for `JS` errors if any, if image is not showing look at the path in the `img src` tag..if the path is set correctly.. let me know once you follow those steps :) (im sure you are able to solve it on your own then) :)

NEW -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vijaishree/templates/vijaishree/engine1/script.js"></script>
```

Put this before and let me know..seriuosly a case of js misplacing(also look at jquery.js if included correctly)  :)  --

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var pns = jQuery.noConflict();
     pns(window).load(function() {
```

Comment: I do everything, look at URL

http://podiumwala.com/vijaishree/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=51&Itemid=27

Its should be come in lightbox, not coming, its opening the images even :(

Comment: @JohanSmith 
Error: TypeError: _this is undefined
Source File: http://podiumwala.com/vijaishree/templates/vijaishree/engine1/script.js
Line: 21 -----  JS Error , look if you are including this in a correct way , use noConflict() and let me know then ..(one more thing tell me what images do u actually looking to come in lightbox??)

Comment: Yea i have defined that script.js in index.php file. I need something like http://demo.artetics.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=137&Itemid=153 way in pop up box, not coming still. :( seems some js issues as well css, what say ?

Comment: @JohanSmith have u checked my latest edit to the answer..its all bcoz of the JS error..take some time..u will surely going to resolve and yes check #KutF comments as well :)

Comment: @KutF No, i was not aware, i have simply installed the modules and its not working :( what to add more ?

Comment: @JohanSmith You can raise a ticket from whr you purchased/downloaded the joomla module

Comment: @swapnesh, its was free, even i used so many, all was showing the same issues.

Comment: Yeah finaly everything is working, Thankyou Swapnesh and KUTF ! Thanks a lot, lightbox css and js was missing :)

Comment: @swapnesh how could i do that, really dont know :(

Comment: @JohanSmith u need to accept some answers :) that Green Tick  :)